# Windows Task Schedule: How to disable taskeng.exe from popping up upon task initialization?

Tags: windows-7, windows, scheduled-tasks, task-manager

After a lot of fiddling around, I managed to launch a php script through Windows 7 Task Manager that mines data from the Twitter API every 5 minutes. The Task properties are as follows:

```
Program/script:
"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe"

Add arguments (optional):
-O - -q -t 1 http://localhost/sentimeter/mining.php
```

However, this launches a `taskeng.exe` popup every 5 minutes, causing me to loose focus on the window that I'm working in. In another topic, I setting the /NOCONSOLE property should fix this, but setting the following arguments in the Task details doesn't work:

```
Add arguments (optional):
/NOCONSOLE -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost/sentimeter/mining.php
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run minimized batch file from scheduler](http://superuser.com/questions/102722/run-minimized-batch-file-from-scheduler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Hidden Start](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart/download.html), it will allow you to run your script without a console window